# CombinationApprovals.VerifyAllCombinations equiavalent using Verify?

Tags: c#, approval-tests, snapshot-testing, verify-tests

Does the Verify library offer Combination Approvals and how would a sample one be implemented?

I would like to implement something like:

```
CombinationApprovals.VerifyAllCombinations(
    DoUpdateQuality,
    new string[] { "foo", "Aged Brie", "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros" },
    new int[] { -1, 0, 5, 10, 12 },
    new int[] { -1, 0, 49, 51 }
    );
```

Is this possible to implement using Verify (https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify#snapshot-management)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [parameterised tests](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/parameterised.md)

Comment: No direct answer from the link. Expect to see more detailed examples @Simon